# JAVA Насколько тяжело таскать за собой класс getSet

Tags: java

В своей программе, сделал класс, в котором находятся методы GetSet куда я сбрасываю значение всех переменных которые мне могут (или не могу пригодится). иногда в методе, мне нужно 3-4 значения переменных, стоит ли мне передавать эти переменные из метода в метод или можно передавать класс, а потом уже имея нужный экземпляр класса, вызывать нужные мне геттеры? Влияет ли это как-то на быстро действие программы?

Comment: Непонятно, а можно пример ваших слов

Comment: можно ли перефразировать вопрос так: "есть ли разница между передачей кучи параметров в метод и передачей тех же параметров, но обернутых в контейнер при обращении к этим параметрам (с точки зрения быстродействия)" ?

Comment: @kami примерно так. просто в некоторые методы мне нужно передать 12-2 параметра, которые содержаться в классе, есть ли смысл предавать конкретные параметры а не класс, их содержащий

Comment: @AzizUmarov сложно представить пример, т.к. нужно будет тонну кода выкладывать. если на пальцах. в main методе я запускаю конект с базой, откуда беру 10-ок параметров, каждый передаю в сеттер. Потом в зависимости от метода, использую, где 1 где 10 параметров. Если в методе мне нужно всего 2-3 параметра, что лучше передавать конкретные значения или же класс, с гетерами, и доставить нужные мне? а точнее, есть ли разница в производительности?

Comment: Думаю лучше передать объект. Поскольку у вас станет один унифицированный протокол для всех. А каждый в свою очередь возмет что ему нужно

Comment: @AzizUmarov ну то есть, особой разниц нет?

Comment: щя опишу примерно. Но в целом да

Comment: @AzizUmarov спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По мне лучше передать контейнер в метод. а там выделить переменные.

```
public void someMethod(ClassA classa) {
  int property1 = classa.getProperty1();
   ....
}
```

vs

```
public void someMethod(int property1, ....) {
   ....
}
```

По существу у вас будет разница в стеке на одну ссылку больше между вариантами, то есть не существенно. А по вызовам считайте одинаково.